# How to compile source code separately in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I hope someone could help me address this fundamental problem that I have been trying to tackle for the last two weeks.

I have a solution that contains 4 projects, some libraries that the project files depend on. In each of these project, a copy of logic.cpp file has been included and it contains a long list of logic which in pseudo codes looks like this:

```
BOOL myLogic(){

 if(...)
 {
   switch(...)
   {
   case 1:
      doA();
      break;

   case 2:
      doB();
      break;

   ...
   case 20:
      doSomething();
      break;
  } 
 }
}
```

For project #1, it generates an exe of the tool. While for project #2, it generates the dll version of the tool that I'm building and the other 2 projects, they act as utility files for my tool. If you notice there are like 20 cases that the logic can run into and it is pretty massive.

So, my problem now is that all these source codes are being compiled into my single exe or dll even when some of these case may not even be reached when deployed in some scenarios. What I want to achieve is to break this switch case and compile 20 different sets of exe and dll. So

1) The application has a smaller footprint. 
  2) The sources could be protected to a certain extent when reverse engineered.

Hence, I would like to seek advise from the community on how do I go about solving this problem, if I would like to still continue using Visual Studio's inbuilt compilation. (I could build the 20 sets of exe and dll with the "Build Solution").

Thank you and I appreciate any advice. Feel free to clarify if I have not been clear enough in my question.

Comment: How would you know at compile-time which cases are not reached?

Comment: I cringe when you say "a copy of logic.cpp file has been included" in each of your four projects. I assume the undelying logic is the same for each project (i.e. the C++ "case" 1 etc. is the same logical case as the C++ "case" 1 in the other projects, which likely means that you should name the case labels). In that case one should use one and only one cpp file and either reference it, possibly modifying it with defines as suggested by Ole, or possibly text process it by other means (sed etc.) in order to derive dependent files from it as part of the build process.

Comment: Hi @Codor, in every scenario that my tool/application is deployed on, there is only one specific case that would be reached, hence I the other 19 cases are in fact unreachable.

Comment: Hi @PeterSchneider, Thanks for your advise! I will probably try Peter B's advice and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new project, that compiles into static library. In that project create separate source cpp files for all the 20 functionalities. (Splitting to more source files are just for the sake of maintainability.) Split logic.cpp into the 20 separate files. If there are common code parts, you can create more source files to contain those parts.
2. Now create 2x20 new projects: 20 exe projects and 20 dll projects. Each of these projects depends on the static library project created in step 1, and all of these projects are nothing but a simple stub for calling exactly one of the functionalities from the common library.

When you build the solution, you will have 20 differently named executables and 20 differently named dlls, for each functionality. If dead code elimination is turned on in the linker, then none of the exes/dlls will contain code that is not required for the specific function.

Comment: Thank you @Peter B, I'll give your advice a try and see if helps. I really appreciate your time for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about some handwork?
Indroduce some defines for your scenarios or use some standard ones like "_ISDLL"
and encase the cases :-) from which you know they can not be reaches in "#ifdefs"

```
#ifdef _ISDLL
case x:

    break;
#endif
```

Comment: Hi @Ole Dittmann, Thank you your time and your advice! I have thought of your suggestion before, but with such approach, I believe I would need to have the "Conditional inclusions", #ifdef condition in this case manually set for 20 times before compilation right? This is something I would like to get away with, I was hoping I just had to push the "Build Solution" once and there would be 20 sets of the exe and dlls that I need.