# Are namespace allowed in c++ conditional inclusions directive?

Tags: c++, namespaces, conditional-compilation

I am currently having this issue with using conditional inclusions directive in my c++ project. I would like to seek advise from the community to see if I'm actually allowed to do something like that.

My pseudo code as follows:

```
BOOL myLogic(){

  #ifdef GlobalVar1
    if(MyNameSpace::CheckSomething()) //Compiler complains that 'MyNameSpace' is not a class or namespace name
    {
      MyClass myCls;
      myCls.doSomething();
    }
    else
    {
      ErrorLog(ERROR_CHECKINGSOMETHING); //Compiler complains that ERROR_CHECKINGSOMETHING as undeclared idenifier
    }
  #endif

  #ifdef GlobalVar2
    ...
  #endif
}
```

I have about 20 conditional inclusions declared, and after defining my selected GlobalVar, I tried to compile my solution and I had the two errors reported as above in the comments.

I wish to find out if I have done anything wrong by using #ifdef and #endif in the above way. As I was trying to test out a suggestion from a fellow SOF member in my question that I have previously posted: [How to compile source code separately in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482450/how-to-compile-source-code-separately-in-c). Thank you!

Comment: Have you actually included the header file where `MyNameSpace::CheckSomething` is declared?

Comment: There is nowhere *near* enough code in this post to determine what is really going wrong. Post a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is complete *and* demonstrates the issue you're having.

Comment: I realized the error was caused by certain headers not being included properly. I have included the #ifdef inclusions directive to mask out header files as well, as such some of the necessary headers which was previously included are now no longer included since the inclusion condition is not fulfilled. I have resolved the issue by adding the necessary header files in the base class. Thanks both for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I realized the error was caused by certain headers not being included properly.

I have included the #ifdef inclusions directive to mask out header files as well, as such some of the necessary headers which was previously included are now no longer included since the inclusion condition is not fulfilled.

I have resolved the issue by adding the necessary header files in the base class.